# What does TGZ mean?

Tags: files, tar, compression, gzip, archive

I can recall my professor saying it means "Tar-able Gzip." I'm searching it in Google and couldn't find it. I know what Tar and Gzip are. I also know what a TGZ is, but I want to know the meaning of the acronym. I'm really curious whether it is correct or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tgz` is often used as a file name suffix of `tar` archives that have been compressed using `gzip`, possibly by compressing it at creation time using `tar -cz`.

It is just a contraction of `tar.gz`, which would be the suffix you would get if you first created a `tar` archive and then compressed it with `gzip`.

On filesystems that enforces the old ["8.3" naming rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) of DOS, using `tgz` as the file name suffix would enable one to store these files too.

If it "means" anything, it means "`gzip`-compressed `tar` archive". Just remember that in Unix, file name suffixes do not *determine* the format of the contents (it's just a help to the user).  It used to be that many web browsers, for example, would download *and decompress* files while retaining the original name and suffix.

Comment: It was particularly useful on systems with three-letter file extensions (like DOS).

Comment: So it's not "Tar-able G-Zip"?

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño Well, it's certainly "`tar`-able" (as any other file), and it is a `gzip`-ed file, but it would be better to say "`gzip`-ed `tar`-file" or similar.

Comment: @Jeano “tar-able gzip” makes it sound like it’s a gzip file that can be tar-red, but it’s the other way round: first you tar files up into a tarball, then you compress it with gzip.

Comment: Maybe my professor was just using it as a mnemonic to help him remember. I agree it would be better to call it that, since it is a Tar file that is compressed with Gzip, it provides more information about the extension anyways.

Answer (score 0):

tgz is the extension of file which is archived by tar and compress by gzip.